# Mockito fails with inlined mocks enabled with Invalid paramter name exception

Tags: java, junit, mockito, byte-buddy

I've enabled [inlined mocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39) so that I can mock final classes but now I get the following exception when running tests with Junit.

When I run all the tests at once only two tests fail, but if I run tests individually then most of them fail.

I'm not using any scala or android classes (that I'm aware of). I am using lombok but I tried removing lombok annotations any it didn't fix the problem.

When removing mock-maker-inline the problem goes away, but I'd rather keep it.

How should I address this problem?

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.example.MyClass.

If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 25.112-b15
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0_112-b15
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0


You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks.
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.

Underlying exception : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [interface java.lang.AutoCloseable, class com.example.MyClass, interface java.io.Closeable, class java.lang.Object]
    at org.mockito.internal.junit.JUnitRule$1.evaluate(JUnitRule.java:42)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [interface java.lang.AutoCloseable, class com.example.MyClass, interface java.io.Closeable, class java.lang.Object]
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Byte Buddy could not instrument all classes within the mock's type hierarchy

This problem should never occur for javac-compiled classes. This problem has been observed for classes that are:
 - Compiled by older versions of scalac
 - Classes that are part of the Android distribution
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:120)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:97)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:200)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:181)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:65)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1821)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:36)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:38)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error invoking java.lang.reflect.Executable#getParameters
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterDescription$ForLoadedParameter$Dispatcher$ForJava8CapableVm.getParameter(ParameterDescription.java:387)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterDescription$ForLoadedParameter$Dispatcher$ForJava8CapableVm.isNamePresent(ParameterDescription.java:355)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterDescription$ForLoadedParameter.isNamed(ParameterDescription.java:227)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterDescription$AbstractBase.asToken(ParameterDescription.java:147)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterDescription$AbstractBase.asToken(ParameterDescription.java:107)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterList$AbstractBase.asTokenList(ParameterList.java:80)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$AbstractBase.asToken(MethodDescription.java:693)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$AbstractBase.asToken(MethodDescription.java:334)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodList$AbstractBase.asTokenList(MethodList.java:53)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.InstrumentedType$Factory$Default$1.represent(InstrumentedType.java:223)
    at net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy.redefine(ByteBuddy.java:698)
    at net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy.redefine(ByteBuddy.java:676)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.transform(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:167)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:117)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParametersException: Invalid parameter name ""
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.verifyParameters(Executable.java:386)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.privateGetParameters(Executable.java:416)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getParameters(Executable.java:357)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterDescription$ForLoadedParameter$Dispatcher$ForJava8CapableVm.getParameter(ParameterDescription.java:383)
    ... 55 more
```

Using mockito-core 2.13.0 and byte-buddy 1.7.9.

Comment: What type are you trying to instrument that fails? Could you add a javap print out? It seems like a compiler added an invalid parameter name and Byte Buddy reads those names using the reflection API what triggers the error.

Comment: It's just a regular class that I'm trying to mock. I'll try to replicate it with something simple and update the question.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 23):

I got around this by upgrading to the latest version of mockito.  Currently it is:

```
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.25.1"
```

After that I had some build errors which was resolved by selecting

```
File->Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```

Comment: Thanks Nari. If you don't mind up voting the answer it would make it more visible to others that it was helpful.

Comment: I imagine the newer version of mockito is using a newer version of bytebuddy, so both solutions are valid here, but upgrading the direct dependency makes more sense than an indirect one so this should be the answer :)

Comment: Same here. I was using mockito-core 2.23.4, and all tests succeded, but at some point they started to fail with the error specified in this post. I upgraded to mockito-core 3.3.3 - and everything got back to normal.

Comment: @JohnAllison : I'm also using 3.3.3 Mockito core version but I'm still facing this issue, any solution?

Comment: FWIW I had the issue with Mockito 3.8.0 when compiling with Java 17 even when setting target version to 11. I solved it by upgrading to Mockito 4.8.0 (I think it is currently the newest version).

Answer (score 10):

Try using the newest version of ByteBuddy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.11</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried this with Mockito Inline `2.15.0` and it has resolved the same issue with my application. It appears as though this is a known issue and has been resolved in the newest version of ByteBuddy.

Comment: I have the similar problem with mockito `2.23.4` using byte-buddy `1.9.16`.

Comment: same with mockito `3.6.0` and byte-buddy `1.10.18`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had a slightly different error, And changing JDK from 16 to 11 helped, not sure yet why it didn't work on 16

````
 - Compiled by older versions of scalac
 - Classes that are part of the Android distribution
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:280)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:213)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.lambda$mockClass$0(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:47)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:40)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:391)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.doCreateMock(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:351)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:330)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:58)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:53)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:84)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1964)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotationForMock(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:66)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:27)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:45)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:74)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:48)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:82)
    at org.mockito.internal.framework.DefaultMockitoSession.<init>(DefaultMockitoSession.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.session.DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder.startMocking(DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder.java:83)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.OpenedClassReader.of(OpenedClassReader.java:86)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForInlining.create(TypeWriter.java:3824)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:2166)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.make(RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.java:224)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.make(AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.java:123)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3595)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.transform(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:393)
    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:244)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:565)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:168)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:276)
    ... 72 more```
````

Comment: I resolved it by upgrading Mockito to version 4.8.0.

Answer (score 1):

Use below dependency in pox.xml file and update maven project

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

Right click on `Project` -> `click on maven` -> `click on Update Project` -> `force update snapshot`

Comment: you shouldn't use latest version but fixed ones

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed the latest Adopt OPENJDK and the problem resolved, (currently temurin-11.jdk.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because my enum class that I wanted to mock (not exactly me but...) had a constructor with parameters that was marked with `@org.springframework.lang.NonNull` and then it failed with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the byte-buddy. So removing that annotation fixed the issue... The End.

Answer (score -1):

for me adding

spring-boot-starter-web

dependency to my pom worked as the interface I was trying to mock was a part of the external jar that used feign client.