# Using mockito-inline in project throws "Mockito cannot mock this class" Error

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, byte-buddy

I am using Mockito 2.23.4 and byte-buddy 1.9.3 in my project. I wanted to mock final classes and methods, so I used mockito-inline following this post [Mockito mock final classes and methods](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final) and setting `mock-maker-inline` inside `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` file in  project's `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions` directory.
I also followed up the post [Mockito fails with inlined mocks enabled with Invalid paramter name exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878963/mockito-fails-with-inlined-mocks-enabled-with-invalid-paramter-name-exception) but issue is still there.
But when I run the test I get the below stack trace.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

Test ignored.

org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.

If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 15
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 15.0.2+7-27
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 15.0.2+7-27
JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0


You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks.
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.

Underlying exception : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient, class java.lang.Object, interface java.io.Closeable, interface java.lang.AutoCloseable]

    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.withBefores(DefaultInternalRunner.java:39)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient, class java.lang.Object, interface java.io.Closeable, interface java.lang.AutoCloseable]
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Byte Buddy could not instrument all classes within the mock's type hierarchy

This problem should never occur for javac-compiled classes. This problem has been observed for classes that are:
 - Compiled by older versions of scalac
 - Classes that are part of the Android distribution
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:164)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:141)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:200)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:181)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:69)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1896)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotationForMock(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:44)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:19)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:38)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 59
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:184)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:152)
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.OpenedClassReader.of(OpenedClassReader.java:82)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForInlining.create(TypeWriter.java:3390)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1930)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.make(RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.java:207)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.make(AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.java:116)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3394)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.transform(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:215)
    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:167)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:161)
    ... 40 more
```

I tried following dependency settings for byte-buddy as was mentioned in the post [mockito fails with inlined mocks](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final) :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
```

But still got no success in resolving the error.My test code and actual method are mentioned in this earlier post of mine: [Getting NPE error when trying to mock ElasticClient in Mockito [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66906500/getting-npe-error-when-trying-to-mock-elasticclient-in-mockito)

What can I try next?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to update your dependencies.

You are compiling your project with jdk15.
Bytebuddy complains it cannot instrument class files generated by this jdk (Unsupported class file major version 59)

Support for java 15 was introduced in [ByteBuddy release 1.10.6](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/release-notes.md#19-december-2019-version-1106)

Note that you dont need to specify the version of ByteBuddy in your project as Mockito pulls it transitively (unless younhave good reason to force a version).

Compatible ByteBuddy version was introduced in Mockito 3.3.10. See [commit changing ByteBuddy version to 1.10.10](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/commit/a8f0a7cd33eb29ec1cdf27d3d916e6db987dac65#diff-02b139e755ab0e27e0b0a6f9845843ef189116955cc340c49a4022587dbb2b52)

Instead of analyzing the history of commits in Mockito, I would recommend going with latest and greatest (3.8.0 at the time of writing)